# Adding Easing effects using Skrollr?

Tags: skrollr, easing

How can I set the easing of the element in the HTML? Here is what I have now. The movement is very choppy and I am hoping that setting the easing to linear will solve this.

```
  <div id="backgrounds" 
  style="background:url(http://forevereverlandfestival.com/wp-content/themes/live-forever/FEEL15-BG-Full-Sized-Web.jpeg)"
  data-live-color="rgba(<?php echo hex2rgb($bg_color)?>,0.8)"
  data-smooth-scrolling="on" data-easing="linear"
  data-top="background-position:0px 0px;" data-10000="background-position:-5800px 10000px;">
```